# KVM High CPU Host Crash

Tags: 14.04, virtualization, cpu, crash, kvm-virtualization

I am currently running KVM as a hypervisor on 14.04.5 LTS. When there is high cpu usage, the host will crash hard, killing display and keyboard. There is no indication of kernel panic or other, everything completely dies.

I am unable to track anything in the logs that throws up any flags. Are there any thoughts on how I can fix this? This is a production server and the intermittent crashes are causing great pain.

I have tested hardware temperatures and everything is well within limits. memtest clears with 0 errors. Until recently, this system was running the same VMs under VMWare ESXi with no issues.

I can provide additional info as request; just let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: I've ruled out KVM by running stress from a live CD. I will try testing the PSU tomorrow to make sure it isn't going bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to high CPU temp shutdowns. The motherboard turned out to be shutting down the server at a lower temperature than necessary (~65°C). This was not related to any issues with Ubuntu or KVM.